# getimagesize not working

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the image size but not managing to do it. What could be the problem?

```
$size = getimagesize("http://getfavicon.appspot.com/http://google.com?defaulticon=1pxgif");

echo $size[0];
```

Comment: I don't get anything. But it should work, I didn't this part of the code. You can see me testing the answers and how they are not working on my site.
http://www.chusmix.com/game/test.php

I copy pasted the code and it doesn't work. I'm not sure what could be the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It returns an array

```
<?php
$size = getimagesize("http://getfavicon.appspot.com/http://google.com?defaulticon=1pxgif");

list($width, $height) = $size;
echo "width: $width<br />height: $height";
?>
```

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/8806e/2

will show exactly things you need

Comment: For some reason copy pasting it just doesn't work. http://chusmix.com/game/test.php do you know any reason why it could not be working?

Comment: @Liso22: var_dump($width) gives you ... ?

Comment: I realised it works with any address except `http://getfavicon.appspot.com/http://google.com` I don't know why as I was using the same address before without problems.

Comment: It had something to do with the URL, for some reason getimagesize()  returned `1` something if there wasn't any favicon  as the site as default shows a 1px gif but if it found a favicon it didn't work. I changed the URL and the code worked anyway so idk. I'd have liked to know why it didn't work though

Comment: isn'T your host banned from that URL?

Comment: no, my site gets the images but just can't seem to obtain the image sizes.

Comment: Why does `print_r($size, true)` not print anything? Nor does imploding the array.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old thread, but this may help others. There is a php.ini setting, allow_url_fopen, that needs to be turned on in order to access the getimagesize parameter when it is a fully qualified (http://) URL. PHP only throws a warning, so if you have error reporting turned off, you may not see the problem. Also, your server's error log may report that "no suitable wrapper could be found".

Answer (score 2):

`getimagesize()` actually returns an array with many informations (not only the size).

Use this:

```
list($width, $height) = getimagesize(...);
echo "$width $height";
```

See [`getimagesize()`](http://php.net/getimagesize) documentation.

Comment: For some reason it just doesn't work on my site. chusmix.com/game/test.php do you know any reason why it could not be working?